# How can I relation a foreign key with a form in symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony

Hi I'm trying to make a relation between two entities, a user creates proyectes, but in the create a project form I don't know how do it.

If I do this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
          ->add('Nombre')
          ->add('Resumen')
          ->add('Creados')
      ;
}
```

I have the following error:

[image: error img]

What can i do to make the form that make a relation and show the user how creates the proyect? It's my first time using stakoverflow, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert the logged user in form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737020/how-to-insert-the-logged-user-in-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the EntityType for a to-one relationship like:

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, [
   'class' => User::class,

   // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
   'choice_label' => 'username',

]);
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), too. This will help you understand other form field types as well.

For a to-many relationship you can use [Collection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Ok it work, thanks you so much. And I wanna pass the actual login user i can do it at this way to?

Comment: @CarlosIbáñezLucena sorry don't get your question, please create a new post if you need support and try to be specific.